# how to load previous month name in dropdown using c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

```
private void GenerateMonth(bool SetCurruntMonth)
{
   drpMonth.Items.Clear();
   int year = drpYear.SelectedIndex != 0 ? ((drpYear.SelectedValue != "") ? Convert.ToInt32(drpYear.SelectedValue) : DateTime.Now.Year)
                       : DateTime.Now.Year;

    int months = (DateTime.Now.Year == year) ? DateTime.Now.Month : 12;
    for (int i = 1; i <= months; i++)
    {
        drpMonth.Items.Add(new ListItem(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(i), i.ToString()));
        }
        if (SetCurruntMonth == true && DateTime.Now.Year == year)
        {
            drpMonth.Items.FindByValue(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).ToString()).Selected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            drpMonth.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method should look like this:

```
  private void GenerateMonth(bool SetCurruntMonth, DateTime currentDate)
    {
        drpMonth.Items.Clear();
        int year = drpYear.SelectedIndex != 0 ? ((drpYear.SelectedValue != "") ? Convert.ToInt32(drpYear.SelectedValue) : currentDate.Year)
                            : currentDate.Year;

        //int months = (currentDate.Year == year) ? currentDate.Month : 12;
        int months = 12;

        for (int i = 1; i <= months; i++)
        {
            drpMonth.Items.Add(new ListItem(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(i), i.ToString()));
        }
        if (SetCurruntMonth == true && currentDate.Year == year)
        {
            if (currentDate.Month > 1)
                drpMonth.Items.FindByValue(currentDate.AddMonths(-1).Month.ToString()).Selected = true;
            else
                drpMonth.Items.FindByValue("1").Selected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            drpMonth.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
```

The problem was you weren't checking the `Month` property when you were attempting to select it in the dropdownlist. Instead you were checking the full datetime value.

**Edit**: I've fixed your issue but I've also just added an extra date parameter to make it easier to test, you can replace this if you'd like.

**Edit 2**: Commented out 'Month' logic so that all months appear in the dropdown list.

Comment: when i was changing month of january its getting (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)error because january takes 1-1=0...so getting error

Comment: NO i m not getting december month ,,when i change datetime to jan

Comment: Wow, tough crowd. Arun I think you need to look at your own logic, the dropdown list is only being populated with the number of months less than the current date. How could it possibly select December if it isn't in the list? I'm trying to help you but I can't write the business logic for you.

Comment: Arun unfortunately I don't know what you're trying to do, I've replaced my code sample with your logic about the months commented out. This will display all months allowing December to be selected.

Comment: i got it  december month,,,but now problem is year dropdown to change according this...

Answer (score 0):

```
private void GenerateMonth(bool SetCurruntMonth, DateTime currentDate)
     {
        drpYear.ClearSelection();
        drpMonth.Items.Clear();
        int year = drpYear.SelectedIndex != 0 ? ((drpYear.SelectedValue != "") ? Convert.ToInt32(drpYear.SelectedValue) : currentDate.Year) : currentDate.Year;

        int months = (currentDate.Year == year) ? currentDate.Month : 12;
        int i;
        for ( i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            drpMonth.Items.Add(new ListItem(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(i), i.ToString()));
        }
       //int month;
        if (SetCurruntMonth == true && currentDate.Year == year)
        {
            if (currentDate.Month >= 1)
            {
                drpMonth.Items.FindByValue(currentDate.AddMonths(-1).Month.ToString()).Selected = true;
               // month = Convert((currentDate.AddMonths(-1).Month.ToString()).Selected = true);
            }
            else
                drpMonth.Items.FindByValue("1").Selected = true;
             //drpYear.Items.FindByValue((DateTime.Now.Year-1).ToString()).Selected = true;
            if (currentDate.Month == 1)
            {
               DateTime year1 = (currentDate.AddYears(-1));
               int yy = Convert.ToInt16(year1.Year);
enter code here
                drpYear.Items.Add(new ListItem(Convert.ToString(year)));
                drpYear.SelectedValue= Convert.ToString(yy);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            drpMonth.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: i got it,,,hope it will be helpful